# Core data search through 2 relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have 3 entities: Person, Region, and Boundary. Boundary has an attribute of 'state'. A person can have many regions. A region can have many boundaries:

```
Person <<-->> Region <<-->> Boundary.state
```

With a Person entity, I would like to find out all the states he has a Boundary in. Can a predicate do this sort of search or will i need to do a nested search:

```
NSMutableArray *states = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Region *region in person.regions) {
    for (Boundary *boundary in region.boundaries) {
        // add state to array
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I'm not a database person and didn't think it out to realized they are many-to-many relationships:

```
Person<<-->>Region<<-->>Boundary
```

Comment: Is there an entity called state? You'll be able to use a predicate to get all the Boundaries that a person has. From there you can work out the states.

Comment: No there isn't a Entity for State, just an attribute in Boundary Entity. Could this be a work around? Create a State entity? It would only contain 1 attribute...

Comment: No, I'll [put an answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister: I think that your solution would also have worked. It might be a bit less effective if `thePerson.regions` is a large set. - Unfortunately the first version of the question was misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ANY" collection operator in predicates does not work with nested to-many relationships. You can use a SUBQUERY here:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(regions, $r, ANY $r.persons == %@).@count > 0", thePerson]];
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Now I'm gonna go in a corner and try to figure out how it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get all the `Boundary` entities that a `Person` has you can use an `NSFetchRequest` like this...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Boundary"];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"region.person = %@", thePerson]];
```

This will the return an array of `Boundary` entities whose `Person` is the one you put in the predicate.

Then you can do...

```
NSSet *states = [NSSet setWithArray:[results valueForKey:@"state"]];
```

Then states will be a set of unique states that the Person "owns".

With the many to many this changes.

You could do something along the lines of this for the predicate...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY region IN %@", thePerson.regions];
```

... I think this might work?

Comment: (You were faster, I have discarded my answer :-) - The last step can be simplified to `NSArray *states = [results valueForKey:@"state"]`.

Comment: Ha! Seems kinda simple and obvious now, thanks! And I think I should have mentioned Boundary can have many Persons. So the predicate would then be @"Any region.person == %@", thePerson, right?

Comment: @Log139: If only one of the relationships `person`, `region` is a to-many relationship then this should work. If both are to-many then a more complicated predicate is needed.

Comment: Ya, its many-to-many relationships. A Person can have many Region, and a Region can have many Person. A Region can have many Boundary and a Boundary can have many Region.

Comment: Then you are stuck. You need a sub-predicate in that case. You also need to change your diagram in your question as it is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: I added a correction, sorry. It didn't occur to me until I tried implementing it.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer, not sure if it will work but the rest of the answer remains the same, just the predicate changes.